# Remove \r\n\r\n from the results in a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, powershell

I have the following code:

```
txtcmdApp.Text = RunScript(@"if (Get-Process greenshot -ErrorAction silentlycontinue –ComputerName  " + txtWSName.Text + " ) {'Open'} else {'Not Opened'}");
```

The results shown in the textbox is **Not Opened** but, when I use a breakpoint it is showing the following in code:

```
txtcmdapp|{Text = "Not Opened\r\n\r\n"}
```

I would like to remove the **\r\n\r\n** because I have an **If Statement** that changes the font color to red in a textbox if the results equals **Not Opened** and it is not working I believe because of the **\r\n\r\n** showing up.

Any ideas?
Regards,

Comment: This is what the debugger is showing. Text box is not showing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe simply remove the newlines?

```
txtcmdApp.Text = RunScript(@"if (Get-Process greenshot -ErrorAction silentlycontinue –ComputerName  " + txtWSName.Text + " ) {'Open'} else {'Not Opened'}")
.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
```

This will replace all new lines (that is `cr+lf` (`\r\n`) on Windows) on the string to a empty string.

Comment: Its now working!  Thank you andre_ss6 for taking the time and for your knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `Trim()` on the text:

```
string result = RunScript(@"if (Get-Process greenshot -ErrorAction silentlycontinue –ComputerName  " + txtWSName.Text + " ) {'Open'} else {'Not Opened'}");
txtcmdApp.Text = result.Trim();
```

This will remove any whitespace and newlines from the beginning and end of the string.

Comment: As you correctly noted, `.Trim()` would remove whitespaces as well. That is not what the OP wanted.

Comment: I agree it isn't _exactly_ what the OP mentioned - I can't look inside his brain, I just figured he wouldn't want any surrounding spaces either if there were any, and I did explicitly mention this side effect just in case. "Just as bad" as a solution that doesn't work on different platforms? Opinions differ though, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: No need to look at his brain. He explicitly mentioned the string in question was `Not Opened` (note the whitespace). So it's not that your solution has a "side-effect", it is that it doesn't work for the OP. And about your _concerns_ on not working on different platforms, the OP (1): didn't ask for a solution that does; (2) didn't say he was using Mono or netcore; and (3) says he's using WinForms, so we can very safely assume Windows. 

There's no need to argue on this simple issue. I simply downvoted your answer because it didn't solve the OP's problems. Simple as that.

And no problem.

Comment: @andre_ss6 `Trim()` does not remove all whitespace from the string, just from the beginning and end, as I also mentioned in my answer. Try it out!

Comment: Yes, of course. Only leading and trailing whitespaces. Jesus, I don't know how could this happen hahaha. Maybe I need some sleep. Maybe I was the one that didn't pay attention to the question. I'm very sorry.

Comment: @andre_ss6 don't worry about it, glad to get it sorted. I make mistakes every single day.